# iPad:Two applications Override when installing

Tags: ipad

I created two projects for iPad development. When i try to install two projects separately on iPad, it override one another. I mean, first i used my first project and run on the device, it has successfully installed, and then used my second project and tried to install, this time the second app overrides with the first one, and now i could see only the second application. I tried to change the different creator for both projects, but still observing the same issue.

Could someone help me what is the issue here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications on device are identified by their bundle identifier, so different applications with the same bundle identifier will be treated as the same one be the system and will get overwritten on install.

Try to set different ones for your application if you use the same ones now (path to change: Target/ Info / Properties tab / Identifier)